# Solving a summation involving floor function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, self-learning, computational-mathematics

How to obtain the exact solution for the following Summation:
$$ C(N) = 3^{\left\lfloor \log_3 \left(\frac{N}{4}\right)\right\rfloor + 1} + \sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor \log_3 \left(\frac{N}{4}\right)\right\rfloor} \left\lfloor \frac{N}{3^k}\right\rfloor 3^k$$

I know that the approximate solution to this is $\sim N \log_{3}(N)$. But I am not sure how to approach this. This showed up as a result of the trying to solve the following the recurrence:
$$C(N) = C\left({\left\lfloor {N \over 3} \right\rfloor}\right) + N \quad{\rm for}\ N>3{\rm \ with\ } C(1)=C(2)=C(3)=1$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @ElliotYu thank you. tbh I am looking for at least hints or at least some guidance as to how to approach this problem not necessarily a complete solution. I have seen a post (although addressing a different but similar problem; a summation with the floor function) referring the Divisor summatory function but I am not sure it's useful here.